# Python How do I find if an number is in a list but is not last number of the list?

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers and want to know if a number is in the list but is not the last number in the list. Maybe something like this?

```
for i in all_guesses:
        if guess == i:
            if guess != all_guesses[-1]:
            #Code here
```

Comment: may be: `[x for x in all_guesses if x != all_guesses[-1]]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `in` to test form membership and slicing to exclude the last number:

```
print(guess in my_list[:-1])
```

EDIT:
OP is not clear as to what is desired output incase there are repeating elements in the list, in particular if the last elements is repeated/present elsewhere in the list. In this case you need to check that it's not equal to last element.

```
print(guess in my_list[:-1] and guess != my_list[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If guess in all_guesses and all_guesses.index(guess)! = len(all_guesses):
    print "Present but not last"
```

The only problem is, it won't work if you have duplicate elements in the list and one is at the end of the list.  as `index` returns the index of first occurance.

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [1,2,3,4]
n = 3

print( (n in l1 and n != l1[-1]) )
print( (n in l2 and n != l2[-1]) )
```

results in

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Slice the last element off your list.

```
>>> my_list = [3, 1, 4, 6]
>>> without_last = my_list[:-1]
>>> without_last
[3, 1, 4]
>>> 
>>> guess = 6
>>> guess in my_list
True
>>> guess in without_last
False
```

If you have to do this queck often (and if your list contains more than a few elements) consider constructing a set for the constant-time membership test with

```
without_last = set(my_list[:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Slice the list with `[:-1]` and check the number with `in`

```
listOfValues = [1, 2, 3, 4]
number = 1
if number in listOfValues[:-1]:
    print(number)
```